# Loop through excel sheets and save each sheet into a csv based on a condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file that has multiple sheets. I would like to iterate through each sheet and check against a string to either read the file after 0 rows or 4 rows. (As some of the sheets datasets start after the first 4 rows) After the sheet gets read I want to save the file as a csv.

This is my code so far, but I am not sure if I am doing the loop correctly.

```
import pandas as pd


def converToCsv(excel_file): 
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = None)
    
    for sheets in df.items():
        if sheets[df.items()] == 'Shipment':
                  newdf = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = sheets[df.items(), header = 4]
                  newdf.to_csv('path', decimal = ',', index = False)
        else:
                  newdf = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = sheets[df.items(), header = 0]
                  newdf.to_csv('path', decimal = ',', index = False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things not working with the snippet you posted :

- `sheets[df.items()]` is not valid. `df.items()` returns a dict like : `{<sheet_name>: <sheet_content>}`, so you can not use it as an index
- missing parenthesis and misplacement of square brackets
- admitting that the loop worked, you are always saving the data to the same file `path`, doing so you are overwriting the previously saved sheet to csv on each loop turn.

Did you try running this code before posting it ?

You could do something along those lines :

```py
import pandas as pd


def converToCsv(excel_file): 
    workbook = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = None)
    
    for sheet_name in workbook.keys():
        header = 0
        if sheet_name == 'Shipment':
            header = 4    
        newdf = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = sheet_name, header=header)
        # TODO: handle the case where sheet name is not a valid file name
        newdf.to_csv(f"{sheet_name}.csv", decimal = ',', index = False)

converToCsv("test.xlsx")
```